# Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, netbeans

I'm trying to follow along to https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html this for an assignment but I'm using my own entity relationship diagram in mySQL workbench.
As can be seen here https://www.flickr.com/photos/93791690@N02/23076476850/in/dateposted-public/

But when I try and follow what is said on the Netbeans site Delete 'select * from category' and enter the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`name`)
VALUES ('dairy'),('meats'),('bakery'),('fruit & veg');
```

But try with my own:

```
INSERT INTO `book` (`price`) VALUES ('20.0');
INSERT INTO `book` (`author_name`) VALUES ('author_name');
```

I keep getting errors saying

```
Error code 1364, SQL state HY000: Field 'author_name' doesn't have a default value
Line 1, column 1

Error code 1364, SQL state HY000: Field 'price' doesn't have a default value
Line 2, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 2 error(s) occurred.
```

Can someone please help me to start going in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to insert two lines,

```
INSERT INTO `book` (`price`, `author_name`) VALUES ('20.0', 'author_name');
```

is likely what you want to do. The inserts trying to set just one column are failing because the other column has no default value. All columns which do not have a default value need to be set in an insert. If you intended to insert two rows here, then you'll need to make sure you specify values for both columns in each insert or `ALTER` your table so that the column has `DEFAULT` values. For example,

```
ALTER TABLE `book` MODIFY `author_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT '';
```

changing the size of the varchar to be whatever your `author_name` column is and replacing the empty string `''` with whatever you want the default to be.

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I wanted however since author_name was a foreign key I had to insert this at the start SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and then it worked perfectly.